# Join Produces Duplicate Rows and ignores Where Statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and when I join them together, the query results in duplicate rows in my results.

The table 1's Primary ID repeated over and over.

The Where clause is being ignored too. It is returning rows that have the two fields in cmID  cmIDtwo, if either of these have a value it should not return them

I tried an inner join but cannot get it to work correctly.

My Goal is to look though an order table and join any existing questions a customer had posed about that order by using their ID.

```
Table 1:
ccOrder
ccOrder.ID,
ccOrder.cmID,
ccOrder.cmIDtwo,
ccOrder.ccShippingEmail 

Table 2
contactManager.contactManagerId
contactManager.email



My Query:

    SELECT 
    ccOrder.ID,
    ccOrder.cmID,
    ccOrder.cmIDtwo,
    ccOrder.ccEmail,
    ccShippingEmail, 

    contactManager.email 

    FROM ccOrder

    JOIN contactManager ON ccOrder.ccShippingEmail = contactManager.email 

    WHERE (ccOrder.cmID = 0 & ccOrder.cmIDtwo = 0) 

    AND contactManager.`email` != ''
```

Comment: Why are you joining on email? I think you should join using ID.

Comment: I completely agree but it is from two different systems so matching on email to create an ID so I can match on that.

Comment: **sample data** and **expected result** please provide both ... I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a while I found a simple change of 
    WHERE (ccOrder.cmID = 0 & ccOrder.cmIDtwo = 0) 
to
    WHERE ccOrder.cmID = 0 AND ccOrder.cmIDtwo = 0

eliminated duplicate entries and returns back expected results.

Love to know why since & usually works.